# Python 2.7 IDLE keeps crashing on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, crash, python-idle

I am running a script where one python file opens another. When the other file is about to open, IDLE python crashes.

I typed this into terminal

```
python -m idlelib
```

and received this

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

and then says

```
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)|
```

and opens that, but I need to use 2.7 so it's compatible with other software I'm using.

TIA.

Comment: Try upgrading: `pip install --upgrade tkinter`

Comment: OK I will, but I am not using tkinter and I don't remember ever dowloading it, shall I try pip install --uninstall tkinter ? @coldspeed

Comment: That may not be a good idea. Lord only knows what harm that may cause.

Comment: Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
Collecting tkinter

Comment: When I use that command line in terminal, I get this error message ^

Comment: and   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/idle.html) IDLE is a Tkinter program. So if you can run IDLE you must have a version of Tkinter installed. Don't try to run Python 2 programs in the Python 3 version of IDLE, and vice versa. Note that in Python 2, the Tkinter module name is `Tkinter`, in Python 3 it has been changed to `tkinter`.

Comment: Now i have "No module named idlelib.__main__; 'idlelib' is a package and cannot be directly executed"

Comment: To run IDLE properly on Mac, one cannot use the buggy tcl/tk supplied by Apple.  See https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/.  For 2.7, you need `python -m idlelib.idle` because there is no idlelib.__main__ for 2.7.  (I tried adding one, but it did not work properly.)  The error message does prove that you started up 2.x, not 3.x.

Comment: @Eli Take note that [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722804/terry-jan-reedy) is a Python core developer focused on Idle.

Answer (score 2):

To run IDLE from a terminal with 2.7, use `python -m idlelib.idle`, where `python` is whatever needed on your system to start python 2.x.  Unlike 3.x, there is no `idlelib.__main__`.  I tried adding one, but it did not work properly. The error message does prove that you started up 2.x, not 3.x.

To run IDLE properly on Mac, without strange, haphazard errors, replace the buggy tcl/tk supplied by Apple. See [python.org/download/mac/tcltk.](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/)